# shell script to ssh to remote host and answer prompts

Tags: python, shell

I have an odd problem i am trying to solve.  Our company is deploying multiple PAN FWs as a lab based environment.  By default they have an admin password of admin.  I am wondering the possibility of using a remote script to login and send the answers to the questions without having to be interactive with it.

`ssh admin@192.168.100.100 "admin && Password321! && Password321"`

something like the above is what i would like to be able to do.  Essentially below is after you SSH manually what you have to answer.

```
linuxhost ~ % ssh admin@192.168.100.100
Password:   (OLD PASSWORD ADMIN)
Enter old password :    (OLD PASSWORD ADMIN)
Enter new password :    (NEW PASSWORD Password321!)
Confirm password   :    (NEW PASSWORD Password321!)
Password changed
Number of failed attempts since last successful login: 0
admin@PA-VM> exit
```

I don't know the feasibility still digging to figure this out or if there is a way to reset that... I am still checking with PaloAlto Docs to see if there is a way you can script this procedure.

Comment: Your question boils down to "How to automate SSH interaction?", right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much I just need to figure out how to run the SSH and then answer the questions.   Once thats figured out i am off to the races.   I just don't want it to be interactive.

Comment: I saw some script using the command line too `yes` and pipe a file to it so that yes answers the question for you. https://www.howtogeek.com/415535/how-to-use-the-yes-command-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

The ssh command will read from stdin which you can supply:

```sh
echo 'hello there' | \
ssh admin@192.168.100.100 'read -r line; echo "$USER: \$line is \"$line\""'
admin: $line is "hello there"
```

So you could try something like the following:

```sh
cat <<EOT | ssh admin@192.168.100.100
admin
Password321!
Password321!
EOT
```

It may not work, but it's easy to try.